# Should we use pipes instead of ternary condition rendering in Angular templates?

Tags: angular

I'm studying the best way to do conditions in my template with Angular. My objective is to avoid unnecessary rendering and function calls.

I noticed that if I have a function in my template to check and return something to my template it is wrong because when I have some state changes, this function is called again every time I do something. E.g.,

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   <h3>{{ getUserRole(user.id) }}</h3>
</div>
```

And in my TS:

```
getUserRole(id: number) {
   if (id === 0) {
      return 'Teacher'
   } else if (id === 1) {
      return 'Study'
   }
}
```

Every time I do an action on my page this function will be called. One alternative to avoid this is to use "pure pipes".

I'm wondering if when I use a ternary condition in my template this also occurs. E.g.,

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   <h3>{{ user.id === 0 ? 'Teacher' : 'Study' }}</h3>
</div>
```

If this also occurs, when do I need to use pipes? In all cases that I need to render something with a conditional like the examples or only if my condition is too heavyweight (an array with many objects and properties)?

Comment: Hi, tried to avoid jargon and explained in as simple as possible manner. Let me know something remains unclear.

Comment: @ veroneseComS - Do not say sorry. I completely understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PIPES(pure) are better than inline ternary operator or calling  a function, UMMM!!**

**Why :-**

Because pipes are more optimize than the given two. With Pipes, angular will render at faster pace.

**Reason:-**

The main reason is the *deterministic nature* of the pipes. This means that if I define  **a function** that doesn’t have an internal state than with the given --*same input parameters*--, the function will always produces the --*same output*--. And this  allows Angular to optimize and call `transform method` only when input parameters change.

**Rudimentary Example:-**
We have a function *square()* which takes one value and gives squared value of the input

function :-

```
add(val): number{
return val*val;
}
```

And this is our list of inputs `3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5`. (total 10 times)

But angular will call internal code of function for 3, 5, 6, 4. (called only 4 times).

why ? Because it keeps a copy of result for each input and if it sees the same input again, it return the output without making internal calculation of our add() function.
Than in this case angular will not use internal code of our add function

**REAL world Case for your example user.id === 0 ? 'Teacher' : 'Study'**

For calculation like these simple, ternary operator might win, because in this example pipes might be an overkill.

**NOTE:-** Above info only applies to **pure** pipes, not **impure**.

Comment: Well explained ! FYI. keep in mind about trackBy feature if you have a list which you are going to update frequently. trackBy feature is kind of virtualDOM  concept of react. It will updated the required DOM and not the entire DOM. DOM re-writing is not at all preferred for performance reasons. Thanks....

Comment: @ micronyks Hello, I have only given the answer to the PIPE question. trackBy is definitely great but we use them with ngFor, not with pipes.

Comment: Yeah that was just a side note.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not use function within the template because whenever change detection cycle runs, it will run the function again & again which is not good for performance of the application.
2. **When to use Pipe**

   When you want to filter the array or objects. ***It is always Preferred to use pure pipe***.
3. Ternary should also be fine IMHO if **the equation is not too complex**.
4. **Most important**

- whenever you use ***ngFor** in template, always think about using **trackBy** feature of **ngFor** *if you are going to update the list frequently*.
- Usually without **trackBy**, if you update ***ngFor** list, it will re-render the entire DOM for it. It is not good when you are dealing with large dataset. It will impact the performance.
- Using **trackBy**, angular will track all elements and only render/re-render updated element. This improves the performance.